# What is the logical error in this loop?

Tags: java, loops

for these guidelines:

Write a loop that reads positive integers from standard input and that terminates when it reads an integer that is not positive. After the loop terminates, it prints out, separated by a space and on a single line, the sum of all the even integers read and the sum of all the odd integers read. Declare any variables that are needed.

ASSUME the availability of a variable,  stdin , that references a  Scanner object associated with standard input.

I wrote this code, but it the HW software will not except it due to a logical error. I cant seem to find the logical error here. can someone point out what is wrong with it?

```
    int sumP=0;
    int sumO=0;
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("enter an odd or even number");

    while (stdin.nextInt() >= 0){
    if(stdin.nextInt()%2 == 0)
        sumP+= stdin.nextInt();
    else
        sumO += stdin.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(sumP + " " + sumO);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to save the value you have read, otherwise you will be used different values in the while loop and the addition.

```
int n;
while((n = stdin.readInt()) >= 0) {
    // use the same value of n
```

Comment: Sometimes when you call the same method you get the same thing, but with streams you just get the next value.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for myprogramminglab - Java

```
int sum=0;
boolean areMore = true; 
int negative;
while (areMore)
{
    int number = stdin.nextInt();
    if (number <= 0)
    areMore = false;
    else if (number %2 ==0 )
    sum = sum + number;    
else 
     negative = sum + number;
 }    
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = 1;
while (stdin.hasNextInt() && number > 0)
{
            number = stdin.nextInt();
            if (number % 2 == 0 && number > 0)
                        System.out.print(number + " ");
}
```

The answer to this and many other codelab exercises can be found at [Java Codelab Solutions](http://javacodelabsolutions.blogspot.com/)